# align android popup dialog with the expected area of the screen

Tags: android, popup

I'm currently modifying an Android application that is already completed by someone. I need to modify an existing center-aligned popup dialog under the dotted lines that are visible in the list view for this application as follows.

[image]

I tried a few different things to get this popup dialog to align with those dotted lines, but none of them worked.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams param = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    param.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    param.y = y;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(param); // param.x and param.y also not working
```

I've attached my expected and actual results, as well as all of the relevant codes below.

**dialog_options_menu.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/option_download"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="18dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivDownload"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_download" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDownload"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
                android:text="@string/download_lowercase"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/light_grey" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/option_like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="18dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLike"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
                android:text="@string/add_favorites"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/light_grey" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/option_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="18dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivShare"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
                android:text="@string/share_dialog_text"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**DialogHelper.java**

```
 public static void showEpisodeOptionsDialog(Context context, boolean shouldBeDownloaded, boolean isDownloading, boolean isFavorite, int y, OnEpisodeOptionsMenuItemClickListener clickListener){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_options_menu);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams param = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        param.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        param.y = y;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(param);

        TextView tvDownload = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDownload);
        TextView tvLike = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvLike);
        ImageView ivDownload = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivDownload);
        ImageView ivLike = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivLike);
        LinearLayout btnDownload = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.option_download);
        LinearLayout btnLike = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.option_like);
        LinearLayout btnShare = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.option_share);

        String downloadText, likeText;
        int selectedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.option_selected_orange);
        int defaultColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black);

        if (shouldBeDownloaded) {
            if (isDownloading) {
                downloadText = context.getString(R.string.downloading_lowercase);
            } else {
                downloadText = context.getString(R.string.remove_download);
            }
            ivDownload.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bin);
            tvDownload.setTextColor(selectedColor);
        } else {
            downloadText = context.getString(R.string.download_lowercase);
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(ivDownload, ColorStateList.valueOf(defaultColor));
            tvDownload.setTextColor(defaultColor);
        }

        if (isFavorite) {
            likeText = context.getString(R.string.remove_favorites);
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(ivLike, ColorStateList.valueOf(selectedColor));
            tvLike.setTextColor(selectedColor);
        } else {
            likeText = context.getString(R.string.add_favorites);
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(ivLike, ColorStateList.valueOf(defaultColor));
            tvLike.setTextColor(defaultColor);
        }

        tvDownload.setText(downloadText);
        tvLike.setText(likeText);

        btnDownload.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            clickListener.onDownloadClicked();
        });
        btnLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            clickListener.onLikeClicked();
        });
        btnShare.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
            clickListener.onShareClicked();
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Please suggest to me how this popup dialog is aligned with those dotted lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you are showing `Dialog`, not [`PopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow). and you want to show [`ContextMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu) in fact

use [registerForContextMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View)) and pass three-dots `View`

then override `onCreateContextMenu` and inflate your custom menu

```
@Override  
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();  
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.some_custom_menu, menu);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Some title");  
}
```

and handle clicks in:

```
@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){  
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.custom_menu_item){
        //handle click here
        return true; //handled
    }
    return false; // not handled
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: You should use [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu) for your purpose

1. Create a Menu XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mute"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="Mute"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_volume_off_mute_24"
        android:iconTint="@color/text"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
        android:iconTint="@color/text"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        android:title="Share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:iconTint="@color/text"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/leave"
        android:orderInCategory="104"
        android:title="Leave"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:iconTint="@color/text"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

2. Method to Show Popup Menu:

```
    private fun showPopupMenu() {
        val popup = PopupMenu(this, binding.layoutChatHeader.imageViewOptions)

        popup.apply {
            // inflate the popup menu
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_channel_menu, menu)

            // popup menu item click listener
            setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.mute ->                     
                        true
                    R.id.settings ->                     
                        true
                    R.id.leave -> {
                        removeUser()
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }

                false
            }
        }

        // show icons on popup menu
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            popup.setForceShowIcon(true)
        } else {
            try {
                val fields = popup.javaClass.declaredFields
                for (field in fields) {
                    if ("mPopup" == field.name) {
                        field.isAccessible = true
                        val menuPopupHelper = field[popup]
                        val classPopupHelper =
                            Class.forName(menuPopupHelper.javaClass.name)
                        val setForceIcons: Method = classPopupHelper.getMethod(
                            "setForceShowIcon",
                            Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType
                        )
                        setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true)
                        break
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        // finally, show the popup menu
        popup.show()
    }
```

3. Open Popup Menu wherever required (for example onClickListener):

```
imageViewOptions.setOnClickListener {
            showPopupMenu()
        }
```